# UISplitViewController: Does not show up when setting it up pragmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to setup a splitviewcontroller using storyboards. The code below is what I have so far. However, it is showing a black screen. I have a storyboard name Main. I have two viewcontrollers in the storyboard. I read how to do this from an article, but can't get it to work. I must be missing something small. Any help is appreciated.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                 bundle:nil];
  ViewController *firstVC =  [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    ViewController1 *secondVC =  [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];

    CGRect frameFirstVC = firstVC.view.frame;
    frameFirstVC.size.width = 100;

    CGRect frameSecondVC = secondVC.view.frame;
    frameSecondVC.size.width = 100;

    UISplitViewController* splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVC, secondVC, nil];

    [self.window addSubview:splitVC.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the split view controller's view as a subview of your window directly. Instead, set the window's `rootViewController` property:

```
self.window.rootViewController = splitVC;
```

In addition to configuring the view hierarchy, this sets up additional state and layout information for the app to properly display and use the split view controller.

(I should point out that instead of writing *any* of this code, you could put the split view controller in your storyboard, mark it the initial view controller, then use that storyboard as your app's main interface file. That's a bit of a bigger change, though.)